How can correcting a basis for the set of errors be enough in a degenerate code
Let $\mathcal E$ be a set of errors that can be corrected by a QECC $\mathcal C$. If $C$ is degenerate, then there are two distinct errors $E_1, E_2 \in \mathcal E$ such that $E_1 |\psi \rangle = E_2 |\psi \rangle$ for all $| \psi \rangle$ in $\mathcal C$. Since $\mathcal E$ is a vector space, $E_1 - E_2 = E \in \mathcal E$ so the code should be able to correct this error. However, $E |\psi\rangle = 0$ for all codewords, so how can this be corrected?

An error is a physical process, and ultimately must be described by a dynamical evolution of the quantum state. $E_1 - E_2$ here does not represent any physically possible evolution.

@ChrisD Consider slightly modified case of OP, where $E = \frac{Z_1 - Z_2}{\sqrt{2}}$. Consider Kraus operators $${ K_1, K_2 } \equiv \bigg{\frac{Z_1 - Z_2}{\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{Z_1 Z_2}  \bigg},.$$These satisfy the condition $$K_1^\dagger K_1 + K_2^\dagger K_2 = I,,$$ and hence will correspond to some valid physical process.

@FDGod Good point.

The issue here isn't specific to degenerate codes. If the "QECC corrects a set of errors $\mathcal{E}$", then by linearity it corrects $\text{span}(\mathcal{E})$. This includes operators like $\alpha E$ for $E \in \mathcal{E}$, and in particular the operator $E=0$.
The problem is that "$\mathcal{E}$ is a set of errors that can be corrected" or "correcting an error $E \in \mathcal{E}$" are imprecise statements, because there's no expectation that $E|\psi\rangle$ describes a physical process in general. Rather, the QECC for $\mathcal{E}$ can effectively invert a channel $\mathcal{N}$ constructed from Kraus operators in $\text{span}(\mathcal{E})$.
The high level idea is that if you write out the operator sum form of $\mathcal{N}$, then you can see that pathological operators like $0$ or $(E_1 - E_2)$ with $E_1 - E_2=0$ don't contribute towards the effect of the channel at all. Similarly, for a state $\sigma$ in a codespace with projector $P$, operators $E_1,E_2$ with $(E_1 - E_2)P=0$ don't contribute to how a channel acts on the codespace.
Below, I will sketch how one might interpret the condition $(E_1 - E_2)P=0$, but the core, rigorous answer is still that the noisy channel we are correcting does not change whether we include such terms or not.
An interpretation of $(E_1 - E_2)P=0$
Consider the condition that $(E_1 - E_2)P = 0$. Using this answer you can rewrite the Kraus representation of $\mathcal{N}$ with Kraus operators $\{A_1, \dots, A_N\}$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{N}(\rho) = \sum_i A_i \rho A_i^\dagger = \sum_i p_i B_i \rho B_i^\dagger , \tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $p_i = \text{Tr}(A_i \rho A_i^\dagger)$ and $B_i = p_i^{-1/2} A_i$, and you can interpret $p_i$ to be the probability assigned to a state $\rho_i = B_i \rho B_i^\dagger$ in the output mixture. When $A_i \rho A_i^\dagger = 0$, then $p_i=0$ and the operator $B_i$ is ill-defined, but we still have $p_i B_i\rho B_i=0$.
Now, for a projector $P$ onto the codespace, this tells us that for any state $\sigma = P\sigma P$ in our codespace we have
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{N}(\sigma) =  \sum_i p_i (B_i P) \sigma(B_i P)^\dagger, \tag{2}
\end{equation}
and $p_i = \text{Tr}(A_i P \rho P A_i^\dagger)$. So for any Kraus operator $A_i \in \text{span}(\mathcal{E})$ such that $A_i P = 0$, we have $p_i=0$. and the corresponding term $\sigma_i = (B_i P) \sigma(B_i P)^\dagger$ doesn't appear in the output mixture.$^1$ So to say things less precisely, the error $B_i$ doesn't really happen in any meaningful sense.

$^1$  Again, since $p_i=0$ implies that $B_i$ is not well defined, we shouldn't actually be thinking of $p_i$ as describing a well defined event involving the term $\sigma_i$ (which is not a state in that case). The core statement is that $p_i\sigma_i = 0$, and all this interpretation about which ill-defined operators are applied with zero probability is just arguing whether the king of France is bald.
